JS - JSON where in for Prisma 5.x.x
I’m trying to migrate from prisma 3.x.x, to version 5.x.x. However, I’m having a problem trying to do a where In, on a JSON column.
This used to work, but when trying in the new version produces an error. Does anyone know how to achieve this on the new version? It’s not listed in their docs. https://www.prisma.io/docs/orm/prisma-client/special-fields-and-types/working-with-json-fields#filter-on-a-json-field-simple
const result = await prisma.user.findMany({
  where: {
    OR: [
      {
        user_data: {
          path: ['user', 'email'],
          in: input.emails
        }
      }
    ],
  },
})

model user {
  user_id           String
  user_data         Json // { email: String }
  @@index([user_id])
}

